# How can i display a 3d object in an android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am developing an app that contains 3D object view with touch control. I successfully load 3D object with touch control in a new activity by openGL ES. But now I want to load that in a page that contains other elements like menu button.
So how can I load the openGL screen in a XML page that contains other elements also?

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple question with a complex answer. You need to use OpenGL ES to display 3D object. I suggest you to use some library. You can have a look to [libgdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) or [Rajawali](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I successfully load 3D object by using OpenGL ES. But it load object in a new screen. I want to load it in the same screen.

Answer (score 0):

The same as with other Android `View`s.

You can, for example, add it programmatically to a `FrameLayout` (or whatever layout suits your needs):

```
myFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById( R.id.MyFrameLayout );
myFrameLayout.addView( GLView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.BOTTOM ) );
```

Where `GLView` is your GLSurfaceView and `MyFrameLayout` is the `id` of your layout in XML.

Buttons and other elements can be added either in the XML or programmatically.